# Why can't an indirect object be relativised?

Tags: grammar

I hope you are all doing well,

As I was reading through *CGEL*, I found out that an indirect object cannot be relativised. The examples were as follows:

**a. He showed a student the exam paper. [indirect object]**

**b.∗The student [whom he showed the exam paper] informed the police.**

Can someone please elaborate on this because the b example sounds just fine to my nonsensical non-native ear :D

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us a page number, please? (And also confirm that you mean *The Cambridge Grammar ....* and not *A Comprehensive Grammar*!)

Comment: It's the *Cambridge Grammar* On page 1044. @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.

Answer (score 1):

In my 19 years of teaching English, I've never heard of such a rule, and to my Canadian ear, your (b) sentence is correct and natural.

To avoid the always awkward pronoun "whom", I'll change the context, but not the underlying grammar:

> Joe gives the wall a coat of paint every year.
> The wall [which he gives a coat of paint every year] is in need of repair.
> *OR*
> Joe also regularly repairs the wall [which he gives a coat of paint every year].

There are more natural ways of expressing this, but the grammar is fine.

Comment: Well, I think I am back to being confused again . I read about this rule yesterday in CGEL. It's the very last sentence on page 1044.

Comment: The same rules and alternations do not apply to idioms or light verbs. Here *give the wall a coat of paint* does not involve giving anything to anybody or to anything. And *give something a coat of paint* does not even follow the normal alternation with *to*. We don't say *I gave a coat of paint to the wall yesterday*. /// The OP's RC sounds decidedly off to me and would need to be "the student whom he showed the exam paper **to ...**". However, strangely, I find that if it was a supplementary RC, it's slightly less offensive "The student, whom I showed the exam paper, informed ...". (shrugs)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Can you connect what you say about my sentences to the content of my answer? I'm not drawing any inferences here. I can't even tell if you're supporting, contradicting, or just commenting. Specifically, are you saying "give" in my sentence isn't ditransitive, or for some other reason doesn't apply to the OP's question?

Comment: That turned into a more interesting discussion than I thought it would be .

Comment: H&P's generalisation does not apply to idioms and light verbs. Your *give a wall coat of paint* is one or the other or both (can't quite tell which).  In *give X a coat of paint*, the idiom does not show the normal dative alternation: "give X a book" and "give a book **to** X" /    "give X a coat of paint" but NOT "*give a coat of paint **to** X". H&P's point is with IO's we need to use the preposition variant: "the student he showed the book **to** ate a sandwich" [in which case, the 'the student' is actually just a DO, not an IO]. This, as we have seen, does not apply to your example.

Comment: Your example "give the wall a coat of paint" actually means "paint X".

Comment: I am sorry @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. The last example you provided confused me even more. "The student he showed the book to ate a sandwich", if we were to say that using a construction other than the relative, I think it should look like this: *he showed the student a book.* How, then, is *a student* not an indirect object?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanNoureldeen No, the RC there is understood like this: "The student he showed a book to [the student] ate a sandwich." The non RC version is "He showed a book to the student"

Comment: I strongly agree (native SAE) that the second in OP example is ungrammatical.   I don't even like the "paint/wall" example.   And delex verbs certainly don't always get a pass ("He makes the company money every year."  *"The company he makes money every year is hiring."   It's worth nothing that CGEL merely says "not normally to indirect objects", but to my ear every example of this we've heard in this thread sounds wrong enough to me that I need "replay" it in my head to understand its meaning.  In short:  follow the CGEL rule.

Comment: As to your actual question which asks WHY the "rule" exists, I say `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.   Such is grammar.   But, that's not worth creating a new answer for, obviously.

Comment: So let me get my new facts straight; any sentence where an indirect object is relativised is incorrect. It's only correct when the sentence involves light verbs or is an idiom. I hope I am right.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanNoureldeen We have disagreement on that point, even among the native speakers here.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through [COCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_of_Contemporary_American_English), relative clauses with "give" and "show" relativizing the (prepositionless) indirect object are rare, but do occur, especially in speech:

Spoken

- We spoke to the one man **who we showed** the video
- the fellow **who they gave** 100 years in the commission case
- She kept asking why her Western educated, Lebanese, Christian, civilized, modern daughter' -and she used all these adjectives -- **who they gave** the privilege of having a Western education-wanted to go back and smoke an argilah which is a backwards, dirty, horrible, uncivilized Muslim habit.

Web

- smart people **who we gave** the freedom to solve difficult problems

News

- Castillo then dropped in on his old guidance counselor, Teresa Snyder, **whom he showed** pictures of himself strolling through palaces

Blog

- You are supporting Islamic terrorists of the friends of Obama, Muslim Brotherhood, **whom he gave** money for their war

More commonly, "to" is used, e.g. "Bertha Palmer, to whom he gave the downtown Palmer House Hilton as a wedding gift" or "My son, who I gave bone marrow to".

To my ear (as an AmE speaker), "The student [whom he showed the exam paper] informed the police." doesn't sound outright ungrammatical. So I suspect it is a matter of variation.